# OOP - design patterns that deal with configuration classes

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Are there any design patterns that deal directly with configuration classes.  Thats is, classes that are simply containers for configuration settings.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ see this site

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Whatever it is you are currently doing (with your simple configuration classes) -- what is it you expect a design pattern to help you with?

Comment: HI @KirkWoll My class is quite simple, but its becoming a bit of a dumping ground for global settings used in the system. Just wondering whether there are any specific design patterns (aside from the singleton) that deal specifically with this type of class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I usually tend to use constants for global settings. Not everything must be a class.

Some will tell you that a Singleton pattern is fit here, but I think different. Singletons are evil. **[See this question on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40373/so-singletons-are-bad-then-what)**